# Table format in webforms

Tags: webforms, theming

I have created  a customized form using the [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) module in Drupal 7, but I want to have a table with rows n columns one part of this form. I downloaded the [Webform Table Element](http://drupal.org/project/webform_table_element) module, but there is no way to configure it or arrange the rows and columns, and mention labels as I want.

Please suggest me a step-by-step way to include a large table in webforms. How can it be managed without coding?

Comment: If element provided by Webform Table Element is not configurable, it probably is a bug in module or in your setup. If configuration is insufficient, we probably need more data - what exactly you need to do, and why / when you are failing? This module lacks documentation online, but we can't quite write it here either.

Comment: see i basically want a table where the first row is the labelled row, while all other following row would contain user entered data.. please give me some solution to have this kinda table in drupal webforms.

Answer (score 1):

From your Comment "contain user entered data" i understood you need webform submitted data in Table format, If so then download and install this module [Webform Report](http://drupal.org/project/webform_report)

> This module allows users to create simple, dynamic reports based on
>   data collected by the webform module. It adds a new node type that
>   contains the report criteria, and the data displayed is updated
>   automatically as webforms are submitted.

See the webform report in below image, hope it helps you!!

[image]

Comment: How do we configure the reports submissions based on roles?